# kotlinでUDP通信をしたい

Tags: android, kotlin

タイトル通りですが、kotlinでUDPのソケット通信をしたいです。
サンプル等が見つからないので、どなたか教えてくれませんか？

Answer (score 3):

サンプルでよろしければ、SNTP の通信を kotlin で作ってみました。
データの中身はいい加減ですが。

```
import java.net.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val socket = DatagramSocket()
    socket.connect(Inet4Address.getByName("192.168.0.132"), 123)

    val data = ByteArray(128)
    val header = (0 shl 30) or (4 shl 27) or (3 shl 24) or (15 shl 16) or (4 shl 8)
    data[0] = (header shr 24).toByte()
    data[1] = (header shr 16).toByte()
    data[2] = (header shr 8).toByte()
    data[3] = (header shr 0).toByte()

    val pkt = DatagramPacket(data, 4 * 12)
    socket.send(pkt)

    pkt.length = data.size
    socket.receive(pkt)

    System.out.println(data.copyOf(pkt.length).joinToString(
            separator = " ",
            transform = { b -> String.format("%02x", b) }
    ))
}
```

やってることは Java の時と変わらないと思います。